# Error when adding a code generation build script of Apollo in swift package manager

Tags: swift, xcode, apollo, swift-package-manager

The error that xcode gives me is:

```
./../SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts: No such file or directory
```

I've seen this line of code in the official script on [the official website](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/installation/#adding-a-code-generation-build-step) , I have xcode11,I'm using Apollo iOS *0.16.0* with **Swift package manager**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few weeks ago. In fact this is a mistake with the Apollo iOS Website Documentation. I realized that when building in Release Configuration the script doesn't locate the scripts in the right folder. However, when building in Debug Configuration the path works fine. I refer to this line `../../SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts`

So in order to solve this problem we have to detect the build configuration type like following:

```
    # Go to the build root and go back up to where SPM keeps the Apollo iOS repo checked out.
cd "${BUILD_ROOT}"

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Release" ]; then
    cd "../../../../../SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts"
fi

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "Debug" ]; then
    cd "../../SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts"
fi

APOLLO_SCRIPT_PATH="$(pwd)"

if [ -z "${APOLLO_SCRIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo "error: Couldn't find the CLI script in your checked out SPM packages; make sure to add the framework to your project."
    exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"
"${APOLLO_SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh codegen:generate --target=swift --includes=./**/*.graphql --localSchemaFile="schema.json" API.swift
```